# Clojure is not generating a class

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I created a new Clojure app with `clojure -Tclj-new app :name myname/myapp` and added the javafx deps to `deps.edn`

```
org.openjfx/javafx-controls {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
org.openjfx/javafx-base {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
org.openjfx/javafx-graphics {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
org.openjfx/javafx-media {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
org.openjfx/javafx-web {:mvn/version "17.0.2"}
```

I copied the initialization of a UI using JavaFX, extending the class `Application`.

```
(ns myname.myapp
  (:import
   (javafx.application Application)
   (javafx.scene Scene)
   (javafx.scene.layout VBox)
   (javafx.scene.control Label)
   (javafx.stage Stage))
  (:gen-class :extends javafx.application.Application))

(def app (atom nil))

(defn -start [this stage]
  (let [root (VBox.)]
    (reset! app this)
    (.setTitle stage "Hello From Clojure!")
    (.add (.getChildren root) (Label. "Hello World"))
    (.show stage)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (Application/launch myname.myapp args))
```

I cannot run the project. With `clj -M:run-m` it returns

```
Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (myname/myapp.clj:20:3). myname.myapp
```

It seems that Clojure is not generating any class since no folder `target` is created. I'm using Clojure `1.11.1` on macOS 12.4

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, would you please update your post to specify the URL, so we can help you better?

Comment: Mostly copied from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978726/clojure-javafx-live-manipulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you really have to create uberjar- you can also use this command:

`lein uberjar`

and then use `java -jar your-app-standalone.jar` in the folder with the created jar (probably `target/uberjar/`).

Also, if you want to display your `Label`, you have to create `Scene` and add that label there. This works:

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:import
    (javafx.application Application)
    (javafx.scene Scene)
    (javafx.scene.layout VBox)
    (javafx.scene.control Label))
  (:gen-class :extends javafx.application.Application))

(def app (atom nil))

(defn -start [this stage]
  (let [vbox (VBox.)
        scene (Scene. vbox 200 200)]
    (reset! app this)
    (.add (.getChildren vbox) (Label. "Hello World"))
    (doto stage
      (.setTitle "Hello From Clojure!")
      (.setScene scene)
      (.show))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (Application/launch myapp.core (into-array String [])))
```

Note that there's a wrapper over JavaFX called [Cljfx](https://github.com/cljfx/cljfx), which would allow you to -among other things- test your project in REPL, without creating any uberjars.

Minimal example:

Dependency: `[cljfx "1.7.21"]`

Core:

```
(ns myapp.core
  (:require [cljfx.api :as fx])
  (:gen-class))

(fx/on-fx-thread
  (fx/create-component
    {:fx/type :stage
     :showing true
     :title "Cljfx example"
     :width 300
     :height 100
     :scene {:fx/type :scene
             :root {:fx/type :v-box
                    :alignment :center
                    :children [{:fx/type :label
                                :text "Hello world"}]}}}))
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I excluded cljfx since doesn't seems really well documented and it's difficult to translate from java examples to cljfx.

Answer (score 0):

To compile the app and create an uberjar that you can run, you might want to use the following

```clj
clojure -T:build org.corfield.build/uber :lib myname/myapp :main myname.myapp
```

That should create an uberjar in the `target` folder.
You can then run the uberjar using

```bash
java -jar target/myapp-standalone.jar
```

I haven't used Java FX before so can't help with that.

Comment: Hey, thanks but I don't need to create an uberjar, just run the project from clojure with `clj` or from the REPL